# Identify Book About Reading of Will

Tags: story-identification

In the 90’s I read a novel (I believe it was part of a series) about a man (had an eyepatch?) and a woman who either law enforcement or mercenaries. They are hired to attend the reading of a will, posing as distant relations of this wealthy family, to uncover some monster, also posing as a family member. There is also a “protector” who throughout history has come to the aid of this family.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall the cover art?  Was it set in the U.S. or another country?  Do you remember any place or character names?

Comment: Man and woman law enforcement duo, and the man may have an eye patch?  That sounds like Hawk and Fisher in the city of Haven.  The stories were written by Simon R Green, not sure which story yet though.

Comment: Thank you. It is a Hawk and Fisher novel, Wolf in the Fold.

Comment: Can you write that up as the answer?

Answer (score 4):

As stated by the OP in the comments, this is one of Simon R. Green's [Hawk and Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_R._Green_bibliography) stories, namely [Wolf in the Fold](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/498506.Wolf_in_the_Fold), the fourth story in the Hawk and Fisher series, originally published in 1991.

Hawk and Fisher are the only incorrupt guards in the city of Haven.  In this particular story, they are tasked with tracking down a spy, who has taken refuge in a ancestral seat of one the cities aristocratic (Quality) families, the family MacNeil.

The Head of the MacNeil family has recently died, thus providing an opportunity for Hawk and Fisher to infiltrate the residence as very distant relatives of the family.

There task is to remain undetected, as impersonating one of the Quality is a death sentence. find the spy (Fenris) and eliminate him.

*The following extract is from Goodreads review*

> > The story opens with Hawk and Fisher trailing a spy. But the spy gets away and holes up in a tower belonging to the Quality (the Aristocracy). The two guard captains must go undercover and pose as distant relatives in order to locate the spy. Unfortunately posing as a member of the Quality is punishable by death and headquarters will not back them up if they are found out. While trying not to blow their cover, the two infiltrate the tower where a new lord is taking command. Unfortunately a dead body turns up and everyone learns that there is an undying Freak locked up somewhere in the tower. Tensions rise and Hawk and Fisher have three tasks; try not to be discovered, find the spy, and try to stop the Freak before it kills everyone.